# SVG: Scale one element of group from specified anchor point

Tags: javascript, html, animation, svg

OK, so I have a group of four elements rotating 90 degrees as I want them to, around an origin point in the middle of the four elements.

I would like to scale the top left block before and after spinning as well, outward from said origin point, but I'm having much difficulty doing so.

Here is a fiddle for my sample (read: overly simplified) progress so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/Vac2Q/2843/

The fiddle's javascript:

```
/* create an svg drawing */
var draw = SVG('drawing')

/* draw rectangle */
var dial = draw.circle(60)
                .move(125,125)
                .fill('#0099ff')

var rect_yellow = draw.rect(50,50)
                .move(100,100)
                .fill('gold')
var rect_blue = draw.rect(50,50)
                .move(160,100)
                .fill('navy')
var rect_black = draw.rect(50,50)
                .move(160,160)
                .fill('black')
var rect_green = draw.rect(50,50)
                .move(100,160)
                .fill('green')

var blades = draw.group()
    .add(rect_yellow)
    .add(rect_blue)
    .add(rect_black)
    .add(rect_green)
    .back()

var angle = 0
var rotation = 90
var spin = document.getElementById('spin')
var spun = 0

/* make rectangle jump and change color on mouse over */
spin.addEventListener('click', function() {
    /* calculate new ending orientation for blades */
    angle += rotation
    var new_rotate = angle

    /* rotate the blade group */
    blades.animate(1000, '>')
        .rotate(new_rotate, 155, 155)

    ++spun
})
```

And here is a slightly more glamorous example of what I'm trying to do re: scaling:

[image]

The first issue is being able to determine which blade is in the top left position after a given rotation. The second issue is scaling itself; I've gotten the blade to scale, but then it goes crazy and moves off the screen at the same time. I'm not sure how to get it to scale properly from the specified origin point (the middle of the center circle).

Comment: Why do you hate semi-colons? They can be cute even though they often make sad winky faces.

Comment: @Jonathan The example I snagged some of the code from didn't use them. I know, it looked weird to me too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.after()` function to chain animations.

I'm not sure if I am using svg.js correctly, but here's what I did:

```
var rects = [rect_yellow, rect_green, rect_black, rect_blue];

// define the animations
var enlarge_blade = function() {
  rects[spun % 4].animate(250, '<')
                 .scale(1.25, 1.25)
                 .translate(-38,-38);
};

function spin_anim() {
  rects[spun % 4].animate(250, '>')
                 .scale(1, 1)
                 .translate(0,0)
                 .after(rotate_blades);
};

var rotate_blades = function() {
    blades.animate(1000, '>')
          .rotate(angle, 155, 155)
        .after(function() {
            ++spun;
            enlarge_blade();
            title.text('spun ' + spun + ' times');
        });
};

// Pre-enlarge the first (yellow) rect
enlarge_blade();

/* make rectangle jump and change color on mouse over */
spin.addEventListener('click', function() {
    angle += rotation
    spin_anim();
})
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Vac2Q/2894/)

Comment: **Very** well done, thank you! So to get the blade to scale from the correct point, you actually append the `translate()` call to the `scale()` call? I'll have to dig into that logic to really understand it, but that'll be so much easier with your working example.

Comment: Yes, you have to take into account the origin of the transformation and the element.  The x,y point of the rect refers to the top left corner.  So in order to keep the bottom right corner still, you have to move the rect at the same time as you scale it.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using `svg.js`. I don't know how it treats transforms internally. But in any case. To scale an element, you typically use its center point as a reference. Therefore you should find the center point of each rect and scale it using that point. (I assume svg.js performs the required translation internally).